# Cue the removal of [queue]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I came across the [queue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/queue) tag and found that just about every use had a different definition. There's no tag wiki excerpt.

Proposal:

[asterisk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asterisk) [queue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/queue) => [asterisk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asterisk) [asterisk-queue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asterisk-queue)

[printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer) [queue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/queue) => Is it necessary to create [printer-queue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-queue)? I'm leaning towards just removing queue from these questions

[postfix](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/postfix) or [exim](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exim) [queue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/queue) => [postfix](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/postfix) or [exim](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exim) [mail-queue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mail-queue) (this one is also questionably useful and prone to misuse, I'm thinking just remove queue here too)